Printing out coordinates of clicked points while user draws polyline in Matlab App Designer
In Matlab AppDesigner I want to let the user draw a polyline on a plot. After each click I want to print out the point's coordinate on the command line. However I can't get the callback or event listener for the mouse click to work. Only after the user finished the drawpolyline I can access the coordinates.
h = drawpolyline('Parent', app.UIAxes,'Color','r');
addlistener(h,'MovingROI',@app.allevents);
addlistener(h,'ROIMoved',@app.allevents);
addlistener(h,'DrawingStarted',@app.allevents);
addlistener(h,'DrawingFinished',@app.allevents);
addlistener(h,'AddingWaypoint',@app.allevents);
addlistener(h,'WaypointAdded',@app.allevents);
addlistener(h,'VertexAdded',@app.allevents);
addlistener(h,'DeletingROI',@app.allevents);
addlistener(h,'ROIClicked',@app.allevents);
addlistener(h,'RemovingWaypoint',@app.allevents);
addlistener(h,'WaypointRemoved',@app.allevents);

    function results = allevents(app,src,evt)
        evname = evt.EventName;
        switch(evname)
            case{'MovingROI'}
                disp(['ROI moving Previous Position: ' mat2str(evt.PreviousPosition)]);
                disp(['ROI moving Current Position: ' mat2str(evt.CurrentPosition)]);
            case{'ROIMoved'}
                disp(['ROI moved Previous Position: ' mat2str(evt.PreviousPosition)]);
                disp(['ROI moved Current Position: ' mat2str(evt.CurrentPosition)]);
            case{'DrawingStarted'}
                disp('DrawingStarted');
            case{'DrawingFinished'}
                disp('DrawingFinished');
            case{'AddingWaypoint'}
                disp('AddingWaypoint');
            case{'WaypointAdded'}
                disp('WaypointAdded');
            case{'VertexAdded'}
                disp('VertexAdded');
        end
    end

With this code I get only the MovingROI and the MovedROI to work. The rest doesn't work. Also it seems that those listeners are only set-up after the object h of the polyline is created. So it wouldn't work anyway to read-out the point's coordinates after each point is clicked. How could I do this?
Edit
I managed to first create the object app.polyline (formerly h) of the polyline, then set up the listeners and only after that let the user start drawing the line. That way the listeners are already active during the drawing. However, only the following events work:
        app.polyline = images.roi.Polyline('Parent',app.UIAxes,'Color','r');
        addlistener(app.polyline,'MovingROI',@app.allevents);
        addlistener(app.polyline,'ROIMoved',@app.allevents);
        addlistener(app.polyline,'DrawingStarted',@app.allevents);
        addlistener(app.polyline,'DrawingFinished',@app.allevents);

        addlistener(app.polyline,'AddingVertex',@app.allevents);            
        addlistener(app.polyline,'VertexAdded',@app.allevents);
        addlistener(app.polyline,'DeletingVertex',@app.allevents);
        addlistener(app.polyline,'VertexDeleted',@app.allevents);
        addlistener(app.polyline,'DeletingROI',@app.allevents);
        addlistener(app.polyline,'ROIClicked',@app.allevents);

        draw(app.polyline);

Of those events, the events 'AddVertex' and 'VertexAdded' only are triggered once the user ads a vertex to an already drawn line. This event doesn't get triggered during a click when the line is first drawn. However I would like to catch the events of those first clicks.
